# How to "Exclude Dependency" from "Dependency Diagram" in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I just want to exclude one dependency by using "Dependency Diagram" in `IntelliJ`; however, I didn't see the "Exclude" option. Is this option deprecated?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. Here is a related issue on YouTrack:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-280311

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.